# Frying Schnitzel

Tags: oil, temperature

When frying schnitzel, is it best to heat up your pan first, then add oil; or add oil cold, then heat ? Also, olive, or veg. oil?

Also, heat slowly, or crank up the heat right away ?

Comment: Hello Deb, you put a lot of questions in here at once. We only take one per "thread". They are also very common questions, so they are already present on the site - I linked to the first one, the others should be available through search or the links on the side bar.

Answer (score 1):

Heat the oil slow to medium; have a proper thermometer on hand to have the temperature near 325F to 350F

If you warm your pan too much and drop in the oil, it will probably explode and burn you and maybe be set on fire.

Be careful to do this in a deep pan; I do this in a dutch oven (something like a Creuset).

As for the oil; use a high smoke point oil (peanut oil, Sunflower Oil).